# Select & Update statement in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure with a select statement first & if the statement is valid then run a update statement. Example code as below, where table1 has two columns `TableName` & `ColumnName`. If there's a record returned from `table1`, then run the update statement where the tablename & column are taken from the `table1` result:

```
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(100), 
        @columnname NVARCHAR(100), 
        @newid INT, 
        @sql NVARCHAR(500), 
        @Id INT,  
        @name NVARCHAR(50), 
        @result NVARCHAR(100)

SET @newid = 0
SET @Id = 1
SET @name = 'aa'
SET @result = 'test'

SELECT 
    @newid = Id, @tablename = TableName, @columnname = ColumnName 
FROM
    Table1 
WHERE
    Id = @Id

IF(@newid > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @columnname + ' = ' + @result + 'where name = ' +@name
END
```

However, the script is not working. Can anyone help on this? Thanks

Comment: You forgot to `EXEC` your `@sql`.

Comment: *the script is not working*, any error message? Unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like this

```
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(100), 
        @columnname NVARCHAR(100), 
        @newid INT, 
        @sql NVARCHAR(500), 
        @Id INT,  
        @name NVARCHAR(50), 
        @result NVARCHAR(100)

SET @newid = 0
SET @Id = 1
SET @name = 'aa'
SET @result = 'test'

SELECT 
    @newid = Id, @tablename = TableName, @columnname = ColumnName 
FROM
    Table1 
WHERE
    Id = @Id

IF(@newid > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @columnname + ' = ' + @result + 'where name = ' +@name
    exec sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: Yea. It's working now. i left out "sp_executesql" for this, exec @sql

Answer (score 0):

You  Execute your Query.

Using **EXEC**
Try This Code.

```
Create  PROCEDURE [dbo].[procedure_name]
 @tablename NVARCHAR(100), 
        @columnname NVARCHAR(100), 
        @newid INT, 
        @sql NVARCHAR(500), 
        @Id INT,  
        @name NVARCHAR(50), 
        @result NVARCHAR(100)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON



SET @newid = 0
SET @Id = 1
SET @name = 'aa'
SET @result = 'test'

SELECT 
    @newid = 1, @tablename = 'abc', @columnname = 'b' 

WHERE
    1 = @Id

IF(@newid > 0)
BEGIN
      SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @columnname + ' = ''' + @result + ''' where name = ''' +@name+''''

    PRINT @sql
   EXEC @sql
END
```

Comment: check this query  SET sql = 'UPDATE ' + tablename + ' SET ' + @columnname + ' = ''' + result + ''' where name = ''' +name+''''

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes to hard-code literals.

```
set @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @tablename + ' SET ' + @columnname + ' = ''' + @result + ''' where name = ''' +@name + ''''
```

Remember to print the dynamic SQL before executing it to check for errors.

```
PRINT (@sql)
```